# Alfresco custom url access authorization

Tags: java, authorization, alfresco, alfresco-share, spring-surf

I want to know if there is a mechanism in Alfresco (share) to prevent some user to access some urls basing on custom config, or can I create a custom authentication level for Spring surf.

If there is no manner in Alfresco, have you any suggestion to interpolate an external mecanism of Spring or other frameworks or librery.

Comment: How about putting a reverse proxy in front of Alfresco and configuring the URL patterns you want to forward in that config?

Comment: I don't think that might be a solution because I'm working on a product not for specific customer,  so I want to implement (or integrate) an abstract mechanism that work with alfresco roles or groups names, the best example is spring security xml configuration, `<intercept-url pattern="/page/**" access="hasAnyRole('GROUP...')" />`